# Classic merge sort (part 2)

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.x

(Initial discussion from [Classic merge sort](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/149597/classic-merge-sort), since it is new code, I start a new thread)

Post my code below, my major question is, I have to create another array `result` to hold sub-parts merge sort result. Is there a way I can just use original `number` to save additional space in `result`?

Any other comments on code bugs, performance (in terms of algorithm time complexity), code style, etc. are appreciated.

Code written in Python 2.7.

```
def merge_sort(numbers, start, end):
    if start == end:
        return
    pivot_index = start + (end-start)//2
    merge_sort(numbers, start, pivot_index)
    merge_sort(numbers, pivot_index+1, end)
    i = start
    j = pivot_index+1
    result = []
    while i <= pivot_index and j <= end:
        if numbers[i] <= numbers[j]:
            result.append(numbers[i])
            i+=1
        else:
            result.append(numbers[j])
            j+=1
    if i <= pivot_index:
        result.extend(numbers[i:pivot_index+1])
    if j <= end:
        result.extend(numbers[j:end+1])
    k=0
    for i in range(start, end+1):
        numbers[i] = result[k]
        k+=1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    numbers = [1,4,2,5,6,8,3,4,0]
    merge_sort(numbers, 0, len(numbers)-1)
    print numbers
```

Comment: _Is in-place merge sorting arrays possible without at least doubling run time?_ (in your wording, `number` lacks "the plural-`s`") Are you aware of [Ford-Johnson merge-insertion sort](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/116367/93149) (and improvements, e.g. by T. D. Bui & Mai Thanh), "Practical in-place mergesort"s by Katajainen, Pasanen & Teuhola (based on Kronrod) or Huang & Langston, and the relatively new, non-stable [QuickMergeSort](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/149443/93149)?

Comment: @greybeard, nice post and did some study, but sure if merge-insertion sort from time complexity perspective, less efficient than the solution coderodde posted -- which only use one additional copy? Thanks.

Comment: `sure if merge-insertion sort from time complexity perspective, less efficient than [merge sort with a single buffer allocation]` well, the attempts at _in-place merge sort_ before "Practical in-place mergesort" were _not_ practical due to increased run time, "the practical ones" have been complicated, _QuickMergeSort_ may not be a merge sort in everybody's book.

Comment: Thanks greybeard, in what scenarios do you think merge quick sort is useful than other merge sort implementation mechanisms, like what we discussed below?

Comment: BTW greybeard, how do you think Ford-Johnson merge-insertion sort? Do you think it is more practical comparing to quick merge sort?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your merge sort run 35% faster by allocating the auxiliary memory only once and reusing it throughout the algorithm:

```
def coderodde_merge(source,
                    target,
                    source_offset,
                    target_offset,
                    left_run_length,
                    right_run_length):
    left_run_index = source_offset
    right_run_index = source_offset + left_run_length

    left_run_index_bound = right_run_index
    right_run_index_bound = right_run_index + right_run_length

    while left_run_index != left_run_index_bound and right_run_index != right_run_index_bound:
        if source[right_run_index] < source[left_run_index]:
            target[target_offset] = source[right_run_index]
            right_run_index += 1
        else:
            target[target_offset] = source[left_run_index]
            left_run_index += 1
        target_offset += 1

    while left_run_index != left_run_index_bound:
        target[target_offset] = source[left_run_index]
        target_offset += 1
        left_run_index += 1

    while right_run_index != right_run_index_bound:
        target[target_offset] = source[right_run_index]
        target_offset += 1
        right_run_index += 1


def coderodde_mergesort_impl(source,
                             target,
                             source_offset,
                             target_offset,
                             range_length):
    if range_length < 2:
        return

    left_run_length = range_length // 2
    right_run_length = range_length - left_run_length

    coderodde_mergesort_impl(target,
                             source,
                             target_offset,
                             source_offset,
                             left_run_length)

    coderodde_mergesort_impl(target,
                             source,
                             target_offset + left_run_length,
                             source_offset + left_run_length,
                             right_run_length)

    coderodde_merge(source,
                    target,
                    source_offset,
                    target_offset,
                    left_run_length,
                    right_run_length)


def coderodde_mergesort(array, start, end):
    range_length = end - start

    if range_length < 2:
        return

    aux = [array[index] for index in range(start, end)]
    coderodde_mergesort_impl(aux, array, 0, start, range_length)


def coderodde_mergesort_all(array):
    coderodde_mergesort(array, 0, len(array))
```

When running [this demonstration](https://gist.github.com/coderodde/de8db7b4bf024b409bbdd55258d92b34), I get the following results:

> ```
> OP mergesort in 17628 milliseconds.
> coderodde mergesort in 11411 milliseconds.
> Algorithms agree: True
> ```

Also, as an additional nitpick, by [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) you should separate binary operators by a space before and after, i.e., not `i+=1`, but `i += 1`.

**Check you range**

If I do something as crazy as

```
ar = [1, 2, 3]
merge_sort(ar, 0, -1)
```

you will get a stack overflow.

Comment: Love your idea and vote up, and pretty smart to use target as source, and source as target in each iteration, and wondering how do you think about Ford-Johnson merge-insertion sort? I am still study it, but it seems it is a pure in-place solution?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot help you with merge-insertion sort. Ask, say, [Morwenn](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/15094/morwenn).

Comment: @LinMa If you replace the word 'target' with 'destination' I hope you'll find a correlation of 'using destination as source, and source as destination' with variable names `S` & `D` [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/149629/88270)...

Comment: @CiaPan, thanks. Is what coderodde posted the same ideas as yours?

Comment: No problem coderodde, I think your posted code already good enough and pretty smart. But how it is related to Morwenn? Did I miss anything? :)

Comment: @LinMa Precisely, except this implementation is a bit more general: it assumes the part of the array to be sorted needn't start at index 0. That's why it needs additional `start` parameter to `coderodde_mergesort`routine and separate starting indices `source_offset` and `target_offset` in each recursive call to a helper routine `coderodde_mergesort_impl` (implementing the algorithm I called `double-array-merge-sort`).

Comment: @LinMa Morwenn can tell you about [merge-insertion sort](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/116367/ford-johnson-merge-insertion-sort). :)

Comment: (My IDE is not working after a Java update: Don't you need to copy from `source` to `target` for a `range_length` of 1?)

Comment: @greybeard No, the copying is unnecessary. The second array is created as a copy of the subarray to be sorted: `aux = [array[index] for index in range(start, end)]` and no data is modified during stepping down the recursion, so when it comes to one-item range, the corresponding data in both arrays are the same, whether you land in the original array or in a copy.